# How to make a function with "not in" operator in Python?

Tags: python, logical-operators

I would like to write a function that test for each vowel whether it occurs in its parameter and returns False if text contains any lower-case vowel, True otherwise.

My code is as follow:

```
def hasNoVowel(text):
    return ('a' not in text) or ('u' not in text) or ('o' not in text) or ('i' not in text) or ('e' not in text) 
print(hasNoVowel('it is a rainy day'))
print(hasNoVowel('where is the sun?'))
print(hasNoVowel("rhythm"))
```

However the output that I get is:

```
True
True
True
```

In stead of: False, False, True

Can someone help me and explain what I did wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: has vowel means no vowels at all right? shouldn't you be using `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: `return ('a' not in text) and ('u' not in text) and ('o' not in text) and ('i' not in text) and ('e' not in text)`

Comment: That works, thank you very much! @Buckeye14Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `and` instead of `or` in your function.  Currently your function returns `False` only if *all* five vowels are present:

```
>>> print(hasNoVowel('she found the sun during a rainy day'))
False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `any(...)` to evaluate the condition and shorten your code:

```
def hasNoVowel(text):
    #return ('a' not in text) or ('u' not in text) or ('o' not in text) or ('i' not in text) or ('e' not in text) 
    return not any([v in text for v in 'aeiou'])
print(hasNoVowel('it is a rainy day'))
print(hasNoVowel('where is the sun?'))
print(hasNoVowel("rhythm"))
```

Output:

```
False
False
True
```